# Enyim Memcached Client does not write / read data

Tags: c#, memcached

I've installed memcached on Windows as a service, listening on the default port 11211.  I know this works, because I can telnet to the server and carry out get / set commands without any problems.

I've then downloaded the Enyim Memcached client (Enyim.Caching.dll, version 2.7) and written a simple test program:

```
var mcc = new MemcachedClientConfiguration();
mcc.AddServer("127.0.0.1:11211");
mcc.SocketPool.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
mcc.SocketPool.ConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
mcc.SocketPool.DeadTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20);

using (MemcachedClient client = new MemcachedClient(mcc))
{
    client.Store(StoreMode.Set, "enyimtest", "test value");
    Console.WriteLine(client.Get<string>("enyimtest"));
}
```

I know this connects to my server correctly, as calling the `stats` command in telnet shows an increase in the number of connections. However, it doesn't call get or set, as the `cmd_get` and `cmd_set` stats counters remain constant.  The call to `client.Get` returns null.

The program does not error in any way. Does anyone know what could prevent the Enyim client from working in this situation?

**EDIT:**

Looks like this is caused by a timeout. Afer configuring log4net to capture the client's logging output, I found it contained the following (in addition to other stack trace items):

> 2010-12-17 14:26:37,579 [1] ERROR Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode [(null)] - System.IO.IOException: Failed to read from the socket '172.23.0.100:11211'. Error: TimedOut
>
> 2010-12-17 14:26:37,626 [1] WARN  Enyim.Caching.Memcached.MemcachedNode.InternalPoolImpl [(null)] - Marking node 172.23.0.100:11211 as dead

I still don't understand why it is timing out though?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After an hour or so of playing around, I've found the answer. I used Wireshark to look at the network traffic to and from the server. I noticed that when using the Enyim client, the messages looked nothing like those when using telnet.  In particular, I couldn't read the protocol commands going across the wire when using the Enyim client.

Therefore, I concluded that the Enyim client was using a different protocol.

A second protocol was added to the memcached server in version 1.4, which is the binary protocol. Prior to that, only the text protocol was supported.  The latest Windows binary I can find for memcached is the one from [Jellycan](http://code.jellycan.com/memcached/), and it is only version 1.2.6.

The Enyim client is configured to use the Binary protocol by default, which was just ignored by my server as it couldn't be understood.

I added the following line to my test program, and things started working immediately:

```
mcc.Protocol = MemcachedProtocol.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue above. I too struggled to find a newer version of memcached for Windows, but did find one eventually.

I've put links to the latest binaries along with other useful resources [here](http://ben.onfabrik.com/pages/memcached-windows-links).